# Subgroup generated by $\sqrt2$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $[0,1]$ with addition modulo one is an abelian group.

Subgroup generated by $\sqrt2$ is dense in $[0,1]$. I think this generator set is $\{\sqrt2 n|n\in \mathbb Z\}$

I know that any closed subgroup of $[0,1]$ which is infinite is equal to $[0,1]$.

But I cannot show for any interval centered at any element in $[0,1]$ intersects with $\{\sqrt2 n|n\in \mathbb Z\}$

I have seen the trick using taking power of $\sqrt2-1$ but this is an additive group and we need to approach it in group way not rings.

Comment: If that's the generator set, I can promise you it isn't dense. For example, there is an open set containing $1$ that doesn't contain any element of the generator set. I can only assume the original question meant $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$

Comment: Why not? Can you eleborate, and Can you give hint about the case when $Q(\sqrt2)$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189397/why-is-this-quotient-space-not-hausdorff) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504600/subgroup-of-the-unit-circle-under-complex-multiplication) for a proof of your statement that the subgroup of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ generated by $\sqrt{2}$ is dense (which is true, of course).

Comment: @DonThousand: Addition is supposed to be modulo 1.