# A subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ containing at most one point from each horizontal and vertical section whose boundary is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How can one build a subset $A\subset [0,1]\times[0,1]$ containing at the most one point from each horizontal and each vertical section and whose boundary (frontier) is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

I don't know how to build this set. I know that if $A$ contains points in each quarter of the square it's enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be two irrationals such that $\alpha/\beta$ is also irrational. What can one say about the set
$$A=\{(n\alpha \mod 1,n\beta\mod 1):n\in \Bbb Z\}?$$

*Edit:* probably I should give some more hints:

1. The fact $A$ contains at most one point in each vertical/horizontal stripe follows by irrationality of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
2. The set $\{(n\alpha,n\beta):n\in \Bbb Z\}$ is dense in  the line $\{(t\alpha,t\beta):t\in \Bbb R\}$. Now wrap that line around the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, using irrationality of $\alpha/\beta$.

*Edit 2:* As Thomas pointed out in the comment, Statement 2. above is not correct unless $n\in \Bbb Q$. One then can modify the set to 
$$A'=\{(r\alpha\mod 1,r\beta\mod 1):\color{red}{r\in\Bbb Q}\}.$$
Note that the original $A$ still works, just not with the given argument.

Comment: did you intend to write $n\in \mathbb{Q}$ in 2.?

Comment: @Thomas: Apparently it is $n\in \Bbb Q$. Maybe I should modify the set. Although $n\in \Bbb Z$ works, the argument needs a little more detail.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain me a little bit morre the $mod 1$ from the set?

Comment: $x \mod 1$ simply means $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, or $\{x\}$, the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: You really only need to show that the projection of a line with irrational slope is dense in the unit square, which follows from a standard argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by constructing a function $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ such that $f$ is identity on irrationals, $f$ restricted to rationals is a bijection and the graph of $f$ is dense in the unit square. Just list a countable basis $\{B_n : n \geq 1\}$ and indutively ensure that the graph of $f$ picks a point from each $B_n$.

Comment: Is $\{ B_n \}$ a countable basis of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$? How do you apply induction? This answer is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

*Expanding upon @QuangHoang's hint.*

---

To show that $A'$ is dense in the unit square, it suffices to show that the image of the map $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(t) = (\alpha t \pmod 1,\beta t \pmod 1)$ is dense in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. This is because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so $f(\mathbb{Q})$ is dense in $f(\mathbb{R})$, which is dense in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ as per our claim. This implies that $f(\mathbb{Q})$ is dense in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $f(\mathbb{Q}) = A'$ so we are done.

The proof that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79051/279515).

Showing that $A$ is dense in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ takes a bit more work. A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983005/279515).