# Condition for ({$n\alpha$},{$n\beta$}) being dense on [0,1]$\times$[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, equidistribution

What is the condition for ({$n\alpha$},{$n\beta$}) being dense in [0,1]$\times$[0,1]? (Here {a} represents the fraction part of a).

If the qustion changes to ({$n\alpha$},{$m\beta$}), then it is fairly easy: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrationals. However, if the question is ({$n\alpha$},{$n\beta$}), it seems quite complex. For instance, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both irrational but they are equal, then ({$n\alpha$},{$n\beta$}) lies on y=x, so it's not dense.

I guess the condition is that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational while their division is also irrational. But I've got no idea about how to prove\disaprove my conjecture.

Comment: You are right. See my earlier question, formulated in a slightly different manner - [Is $\{ (e^{2\pi i a n},e^{2\pi i b n }) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ dense in the torus, where $a,b$ irrationals such that $a/b$ irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983005/279515)