# Riemannian metric induced by $F(z)=z^2$ but without complex variables or covering spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I briefly learned about covering spaces in an algebraic topology book but did not study in too much detail. I would like to try to restate [Example 1.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEvqi.png) **without complex variables and covering spaces**.

[image]

- The context is that [Example 1.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEvqi.png) makes me question [Example 1.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlF4y.png), which I ask about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268535/does-the-riemannian-metric-induced-by-a-diffeomorphism-f-exist-because-of-the). I actually have more to ask about [Example 1.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEvqi.png), and I would prefer that I would not have to go back to covering spaces and that I could think about $S^1$ in $\mathbb R^2$ instead of in $\mathbb C$.
- Note: I assume [Example 1.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEvqi.png) is in fact correct even though $F$ is not injective. (I ask about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268535/does-the-riemannian-metric-induced-by-a-diffeomorphism-f-exist-because-of-the), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268542/pushfoward-of-smooth-vector-field-is-smooth) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269386/what-is-the-induced-orientation-on-a-1-manifold-with-boundary-that-is-the-image).)

**Is the following restatement correct?**

1. Let $N$ and $M$ be the unit circle $S^1$ this time in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $F: N \to M$ be this time given by $F(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$.
2. I make no mention of "2-sheeted covering space map".
3. My understanding is that

   - 3a. no particular Riemannian metric for $M$ in the original [Example 1.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEvqi.png) is given and
   - 3b. the one $M$ could get from $\mathbb R^2$ is pointed out merely as a possibility.
4. For any (see (3)), Riemannian metric $\langle, \rangle$ on $M$, we have that for any $p \in N$ and $v,w \in T_pN$, $\langle v, w\rangle'_p := \langle F_{*,p}v, F_{*,p}w\rangle_{F(p)}$ defines an inner product on $T_pN$.
5. From (4), we get an assignment $\langle, \rangle': N \to \bigcup_{p \in N} \{\text{inner products on} \ T_pN\}$
6. $\langle, \rangle'$ is a Riemannian metric on $N$ if $F$ is smooth and if  $\langle, \rangle'$ is smooth (as defined in [Definition 1.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXLIC.png)).
7. $F$ and $\langle, \rangle'$ are (somehow; this is what I intend to ask about in another question assuming this restatement is correct) smooth here in the restatement as in the original [Example 1.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEvqi.png).
8. Therefore, by (6) and (7), $\langle, \rangle'$ is a Riemannian metric on $N$.
9. Again, $F$ is metric-preserving but not an isometry since $F$ is still not a diffeomorphism since $F$ is still not injective.

Comment: This looks fine. It should be pretty obvious that $F$ is smooth: just look at the formula you wrote for $F$ (and if you knew complex variables, you wouldn't even need to rewrite the formula, you could immediately conclude smoothness from the formula $F(z)=z^2$). If you compute the correct formula for $\langle,\rangle'$, you'll also be able to look at it and immediately conclude smoothness.

Comment: @LeeMosher I made a mistake. I get that $F$ is smooth. It's the $\langle , \rangle'$'s smoothness I intend to ask about (in another question). Thanks a lot for the verification.