# Is the differential between tangent bundles $F_*: TN \to TM$ smooth?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, diffeomorphism

Let $F: N \to M$ be a smooth map of smooth manifolds (with [dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if)). Let $F_{*,p}: T_pN \to T_{F(p)}M$ be the differential at $p \in N$. Let $F_*: TN \to TM$ be the map between tangent bundles given by $F_*(X_p)=F_{*,p}(X_p)$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307906/if-fm-to-n-is-a-smooth-embedding-then-so-is-dftm-to-tn) says $F_*$ is a smooth embedding if $F$ is a smooth embedding.

What are some sufficient conditions to say $F_*$ is smooth besides $F$ being a smooth embedding?

- I'm not really interested in deducing $F_*$ to be a smooth embedding or topological embedding. I'm just hoping for smooth for [1.4 here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268542/pushfoward-of-smooth-vector-field-is-smooth).
- Some guide questions:

  1. If $F$ were smooth but not a smooth embedding, then is $F_*$ no longer necessarily smooth?
  2. What if $F$ were smooth and injective?
  3. What if $F$ were a smooth non-injective local diffeo?
  4. What if $F$ were a smooth non-injective immersion but not local diffeo?
  5. What if $F$ were a smooth injective immersion but not a topological embedding (My understanding is smooth embedding = smooth injective immersion + topological embedding)?
  6. I think each $F_{*,p}$ is [smooth as a map of manifolds, besides linear as a map of vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190944/is-the-differential-at-a-regular-point-a-vector-space-isomorphism-of-tangent-sp). What does this mean for $F_*$?

Comment: Any derivative of a $C^{\infty}$ function is $C^{\infty}$ pretty much by definition. Using this you can deduce that locally the differential is smooth, and hence globally.

Comment: @leibnewtz Thanks! Your second sentence refers to guide question (6)?

Comment: @leibnewtz Wait so to clarify, even if $F$ were not an embedding, $F_*$ is still smooth?

Comment: Yup. The map $F_*$ is always smooth as long as $F$ is

Comment: @leibnewtz Thanks! Also, good intuition in your first sentence in your first comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is still smooth. If $F\in \mathscr{C}^\infty(M,N)$, then fixing $p\in M$ and local coordinates $(x^1,\ldots, x^n)$  centred at $p$ on a trivializing neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ for $TM\to $M, and fixing analogous coordinates on $(y^1,\ldots, y^m)$ centred at $F(p)$ on a neighborhood $V\subseteq N$ containing $F(U)$ trivializing  $TN\to N$, we can write down $F_*: TM\to TN$ in local coordinates as a map $TU\to TV$.

In local coordinates, $F$ is given by an $m-$tuple of smooth functions, $y^i=F_i(x^1,\ldots, x^n)$ for $1\le i \le m$. And given the local trivialization condition we can view $TU\cong U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $TV\cong V\times \mathbb{R}^m$. Then $F_*:U\times \mathbb{R}^n\to V\times \mathbb{R}^m$ is $F\times L$ where 
$$L|_{\{x\}\times \mathbb{R}^n}=L_x:\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}^n\to \{F(x)\}\times\mathbb{R}^m$$
is a linear transformation and the transformations $L_x$ vary smoothly according to the choice of $x\in U$. So, denoting the variable in $U$ by $x$ and the variable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $y$, $F_*$ can be  viewed as a map $F_*(x,y)=(F(x),L_x(y))$. All the components  are smooth, and hence so is $F_*$.

Comment: I was expecting just some link or reference to a textbook since I didn't really show effort into understanding how $TM$ and $TN$ are smooth manifolds in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Reviewing that construction will surely be a useful exercise.

Comment: Of course. Someday, I'll return to it.

Comment: Careful — the linear transformation varies smoothly in the $x$ variables; your notation suggests that it is a fixed linear map.

Comment: You're right. Thanks Ted :)